# When I click on next or previous button, I need to pass date in to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a calendar. When page loads I wrote an ajax request to fetch 2 months holidays dates from database and disabled that dates in calendar. This is working fine.

When I click on next or previous button, I need to pass date in to a function `getMessage()` to check holidays with database. If any dates matching I need to get response and disable that dates in calendar.

So, I have added a function. But, when I move next and previous click event outside function `getMessage().done()` is not working.

When I click next and previous button, How can I pass dates in to the function `getMessage()`?

```
var date = '';
function getMessage( date ) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cabinowner/bookings/availability',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { date: date },
            success: function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.disableDates);
            }
        });
    }, 0);
    return deferred.promise();
}


getMessage().done(function(response) {
    var input = document.getElementById('daterange');
    var datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(input, {
        maxNights: 60,
        format: 'DD.MM.YY',
        disabledDates:response,
        enableCheckout: true
    });
});

// Next and Previous click event
var seletedDate = moment(new Date());

$('#month-2-daterange').on('click', '.datepicker__month-button--next', function() {
    var lastDayOfNextMonth = moment(seletedDate.add(1, "M")).endOf('month');
    seletedDate = lastDayOfNextMonth;
    getMessage( lastDayOfNextMonth );
});

$('#month-2-daterange').on('click', '.datepicker__month-button--prev', function() {
    var lastDayOfPreviousMonth = moment(seletedDate.add(-1, "M")).endOf('month');
    seletedDate = lastDayOfPreviousMonth;
    getMessage( lastDayOfPreviousMonth );
});
```

Comment: why is this a php question? and database related?

Comment: I removed that tag.